# VirtualBox fullscreen mode problem

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, 64-bit, virtualbox, fullscreen

I have a slightly weird issue with VirtualBox. My host OS is Windows 7 (64-bit) and guest OS is Ubuntu 10.10(64-bit). When I switch to fullscreen mode in VirtualBox, Ubuntu display resizes to fit my screen size. however, after that the display is not updated. So if I click a menu or something I don't see it appear. but it seems to work in the background.

if I click a menu in fullscreen mode, I don't see anything happen, but if then switch to windowed mode I see the menu already open. I have installed virtuabox guest additions.

if any has a similar issue or has found a solution please let me know thanks.

Comment: Have you had any resolution on this problem? I am suffering from a similar issue with an Ubuntu 10.10 guest running on VirtualBox 4.0.2 on a Windows 7 host

Comment: @bunn_online: Not yet. I thought it might have been a bug with a 64-bit version so now I'm running Win7(64-bit) and Ubunut 10.10 32-bit. still the same issue. I reported it but no fix yet. :( I'm using VirtualBox 4.04. must be win7 64bit issue.

Comment: @Atharval: Likewise - I have just upgraded to virtualbox 4.0.4, and upgraded the guest additions on my ubuntu 10.10 VM and I still have the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you post a link to the VirtualBox ticket so we can track its progress?

Comment: @Jacob: I would but I've lost the link. Sorry

Comment: I have created a new ticket: http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8622

Comment: @Jacob: this was probably the ticket: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6089 , what solved it for me was disabling 3D acceleration in the VM settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. I've had similar display bugs with Ubuntu + VirtualBox as well, but nothing that I could not work around. I would report this to VirtualBox - they are usually pretty good about getting things like this fixed, especially for high-profile OS'es like Ubuntu. Keep in mind that Ubuntu 10.10 is only 3 days old, and of course may have some new "features" that VirtualBox hasn't compensated for yet.

Answer (score 0):

I fought with this one for a several hours (++++). What I found is that for some reason when switching from fullscreen to scaled mode that I lost the menu and status icons, hence lost control. The VM would stretch and it looked like it was stretched but still no menu. I fought this, even looked a vboxmanage for a solution. It was driving me crazy.

I searched and searched and I finally found the answer and here is the solution to getting your menus back. What you need to do is use a shortcut. In the menus all of the functions have corresponding shortcuts, but what if you have no access to the "hostkey". Well the answer is to press the [ctrl] + [->] keys and [F] key. This will toggle your screen mode and recover your menus and thus your access.

It is a simple answer, but a maddening difficult one to find the solution. I thank the person who posted the answer, and unfortunately I didn't remember their screen name, but my thanks goes out to them once again.

I hope this helps,
Jim